# Does a set of nested subspaces in a Hilbert space have a concise name?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, hilbert-spaces

Let ${\cal H}$ be a Hilbert space (separable, if it matters), and let $X$ be a set of closed subspaces with the property that for all ${\cal P},{\cal Q}\in X$, we have either ${\cal P}\subset {\cal Q}$ or ${\cal Q}\subset {\cal P}$. We can assume that $X$ includes the trivial subspaces ${\cal H}$ and $\varnothing$ if that makes a difference. The set $X$ of closed subspaces is *not* necessarily countable.

Does such an $X$ have a concise name?

I'm not a mathematician. I tried searching for keywords like "sequence of subspaces", "nested subspaces", and "filter" (just guessing), but I didn't recognize anything relevant.

I also tried looking in the context of "resolution of the identity," which I suppose is what $X$ would be called if it were described in terms of projection operators instead of subspaces, but I didn't find any clear statements about whether or not that name still applies when $X$ is described in terms of closed subspaces.

Comment: If no one replies with a standard name you could call it a chain.

Comment: See also 'filtration'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a set $X$ is typically called a *nest* of subspaces.  You could also call it a *chain* of subspaces: the word *chain* is used very broadly in mathematics to mean "totally ordered set", especially a totally ordered subset of a partially ordered set (what you are describing is exactly a totally ordered subset of the partially ordered set of closed subspaces).

Comment: Perfect! Now that I know what to search for, I found immediate confirmation on the first page in ["Nests of subspaces in Banach space and their order types"](https://www.ams.org/tran/1992-331-01/S0002-9947-1992-1050084-5/S0002-9947-1992-1050084-5.pdf): "A _nest_ $N$ is a family of closed subspaces of a Banach space $X$ totally ordered by inclusion."  Exactly what I needed. Thanks!